# How to find the length of all roads inside a polygon in google map?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to develop a web application that uses 'Google Map' (JavaScript API).

The user should be able to draw a polygon on the map, and then the system calculates the length of all roads on that polygon.

I can draw the polygon on the map, but I don't know how to calculate the length of roads that are inside the polygons.

How can I do this?

I am using 'ASP.Net MVC' and I am able to send the polygons data to the server if it is easier to calculate it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calculating the length of the sides of the polygon, that is much easier, as the sides are straight lines from one corner to another. You will need to declare a point of origin, (0,0), then find where each of the corners end, then calculate the length of that single side of the polygon using the distance formula, (that square root formula from middle school that we all loved so much): http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php

If instead, you are trying to calculate the length of the individual roads that fall within the polygon. This would be much more tricky, as there are not very many roads that are perfectly straight lines. You'll need to use the arch length formula: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx

Both formulas are easy to use, but the difficult part is setting up the equations for each of the lines. The curved lines will be much more difficult as you will need to somehow graph the roads using equations. Which depending on how Google Map's API works, you may have to get creative with you mathematical logic.

I would be interested in coding this with you. Do you have a GitHub repository?

Comment: I am looking to find the length of all roads that are inside the polygon and not the size of polygon sides.Assume that the user draw a polygon that covers London city center, I want to calculate the length of all roads that are inside that polygon.

Comment: Wow. Okay. That might me a little difficult to rebuild the wheel on. Do you consider all the neighborhood subdivisions as roads? What about dirt roads?

It would be easier if you found a way to manipulate the Distance Matrix API to return information in such a way that you just have to sum it up.

I would suggest that you attempt to get from the API a list of ALL roads that fall inside that polygon, and their respective length. Then sum them together. This logic would work for any roads that both begin, and end, within the polygon. However, not for example, hwy 85 that goes from FL to NY.

Comment: If a road did begin and end outside the polygon, for example imagine a single raw spaghetti  laying across the top of a glass of water. (The spaghetti being the road, and the glass's rim being the metaphorical polygon.) You would need to trim off the ends of the spaghetti, on both sides, exactly where the glass makes contact with it. In which case, you may be able to manipulate the Distance Matrix API to "trim off" the road by setting the starting and ending points of map directions, to match that of the polygon's parameter.

Comment: which api call give me the list of roads that fell inside a polygon?

Comment: Are you able to get all the corners of the polygon in terms of longitude or latitude? if so, you can use simple linear algebra to derive an equation to find every single point that falls on the perimeter of the polygon, in terms of latitude and longitude. Then, if any of the roads intercept the perimeter, you have a way of checking if this is true or not.

Comment: containsLocation()

containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)

To find whether a given point falls within a polygon, pass the point and the polygon to google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(). The functions returns true if the point is within the polygon or on its edge